# What's up with this strange new hechsher?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

All of a sudden, I’ve seen the [hechsher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hechsher) shown in these photos popping up on various products. I’ve never seen it before, and I don’t see it listed on any of the usual online hechsher lists.

[image: New hechsher on spinach] [image: New hechsher on cereal]

- Have you seen this mark on any products? (Pics please, if you have!)
- Do you know anything about who’s behind it and in what ways (if any) it differs from other hechshers?
- Have any recognized authorities commented on its reliability?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I visited the link shown on that symbol
(http://is.gd/ocmon) and discovered the
following FAQ written by the hechsher’s originators (copied here [with
permission](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)):

## O-Cmon FAQ

[image: O-Cmon_KOSHER]

### What is the O-Cmon?

The O-Cmon is the world’s first crowd-sourced Kosher certification.
Like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org) or
[Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com), we take
advantage of the wisdom, efforts, and interests of the crowds to
generate high-quality kosher certification on a wide variety of
products with very low organizational or procedural overhead.

Unlike the legacy hechshers, which flow halachic authority down from
centralized [posekim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posek) to
professional field personnel to products to consumers, the O-Cmon
flows the authority sideways, from consumers, or rather,
[*pro*-sumers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosumer) to products and
each other. Instead of relying on expensive inspection processes and
time-consuming Halachic research, the O-Cmon takes advantage of each
prosumer’s God-given common sense and Jewish knowledge.

### What do the name and symbol mean?

The O-Cmon symbol can be read in either English or Aramaic to pose two
questions that it empowers **you** to answer:

- Oh, c’mon! How could this not be kosher? *Of course, it is!*
- ?כמאן - Says who? *Says me!*

### Who is behind the O-Cmon?

**You**, the prosumer, are behind the O-Cmon. You decide what to apply
it to, and why.

The team facilitating the great certification work that you do for the
O-Cmon is:

- Rabbi Benny Neviim, Chief Rabbinic Visionary Officer
- Rabbi Chezzi Polk, Chief Rabbinic Crowd Instigation Officer

### How was the O-Cmon founded?

Rabbi Neviim is a big fan of the crowd-sourced Jewish Q&A site
[Mi Yodeya](http://mi.yodeya.com), where a
crowd of people who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition ask
great questions and provide each other with fast, interesting,
well-sourced, peer-reviewed answers. The main problem he sees with
that site is its old-fashioned
[insistence](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/faq#notes) that it “does
not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice” and that users
[should](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9146/why-is-it-necessary-to-ask-a-rabbi)
consult their own Rabbi for personal, practical guidance.

Rabbi Neviim saw the need to go one step further in taking advantage
of the wisdom of the crowd. Instead of just getting discussion and
information from other prosumers, he reasoned, why not get
full-fledged Halachic decisions from them? Rabbi Neviim then joined up
with Rabbi Polk, a world-renowned expert in empowering members of the
community to make and promulgate their own decisions.

### How can I use the O-Cmon?

1) Download any of the following graphics.
*NOTE: If you have labels bearing our old web address, which started "jewi.sh", please discard them, as that link doesn't work anymore.*

[image: O-Cmon_KOSHER] [image: O-Cmon_PAREVE] [image: O-Cmon_PASSOVER]

2) Find products or services that you feel aren’t getting the kosher
certification they deserve. This includes products or services that
you produce yourself, and that the legacy hechshers would therefore
never touch. One example of this latter category would be your
home-made [Mishloach
Manot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mishloach_manot) packages.

3) Affix the O-Cmon label to these products and services.

4) (Optional, but recommended) Post a photo of the newly-certified
product to the O-Cmon’s [home page](http://is.gd/ocmon) and to your
social networks, so that your friends can benefit from your applied
expertise.

### Legal Notices

Unlike the typical legacy hechsher, which wraps its symbol in
trademark protection and hires aggressive litigators to hound anyone
who uses the symbol without the Draconian rules handed down from on
high by the hechsher’s central authorities, the O-Cmon promotes public
sharing of its certification by:

- Releasing all of its materials under a [Creative Commons BY-SA
  3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license. That
  means that prosumers are welcome to reuse and remix the O-Cmon as long
  as they acknowledge where it came from (which the link to our home
  page on the bottom of the symbol takes care of) and agree to share
  their work with other prosumers.
- Making its [home page](http://is.gd/ocmon) a community-editable
  wiki, so that even the information about the O-Cmon itself can benefit
  from the wisdom of the crowd.

**Please do not adhere O-Cmon stickers to products that you do not own.** Unfortunately, the prosumerist movement that we are trying to promote has not yet been adopted widely enough yet, so your educational impulse is likely to be considered vandalism by the products' owners. <sub>In addition, consumers who encounter the product may mistakenly think that it's certified by an actual hechsher, rather than a Purim joke.</sub>

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm the only one who finds this a bit offputting. I mean, I know that some hechshers are questionable, but at least then it usually comes down to one rabbi representing the hechsher (OU being the major exception). With this label, though, any moron with a printer can slap a label on some food. In today's world, where there are almost countless possibilities for kosher food with a reliable hechsher, I just don't see the value of this (other than someone trying to sell their own baked goods - and let's be honest, the majority of those people's friends know if it's kosher or not)

Comment: Rabbi Neviim: Can we get some other variants, like Cholov Yisroel and Yoshon?

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, c'mon, isn't regular kosher good enough anymore?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Very well. Rabbi Neviim: Can we get the current O-Cmon labels to include the word Meikil after the word Kosher?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Good news! In recent archaeological digs, they found a O-Cmon label which I think is the perfect one to adopt for their Yoshon certification: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8n04a.jpg

Comment: @DoubleAA I vehemently protest your comments here. Anyone not eating Cholov Yisroel and Yoshon is not keeping kosher. Kosher BY DEFAULT means those things, therefore different stickers are not needed. I don't remember the exact verse and chapter, will try to find. I also vote for deleting your comments, as they are obviously based on karaite beliefs.

Comment: I think it's fair to say כמאן דליתא דמי.

Comment: The newest O-Cmon product: the Shabbos app (https://twitter.com/mi_yodeya/status/517627719052713984).

Answer (score 11):

It's not only on stickers. I recently saw it preprinted on the label of a soda can:
[image: photograph]

Comment: I'm surprised that one doesn't have an "O-Cmon_CHAZER_TREIF" on it.

Comment: Please tell me the soda flavor is fake too!

Comment: I can't imagine who would want to drink a kosher diet coke with bacon flavor! That just seems unseemly disgusting, hechsher or no.

Comment: Despite my comment and answer about the appropriateness of the joke, this one was pretty funny. +1 on this one from me.

Comment: Diet Coke is bad enough to start with. I don't imagine that adding bacon would actually improve matters in any way whatsoever.

Answer (score 11):

I've since seen it on these non-food items:

[image: O-Cmon on paper towels]

[image: O-Cmon on a book]

[image: O-Cmon on a document]

Comment: +1 on the Slifkin Hechsher. BTW, if you can teach me how to get a $500,000 tax refund, I'll be your best friend for life.

Comment: @SethJ, you mean you have to do something other than just put that amount down in the "Refund" field on the form? That's what I did, and apparently, it's perfectly kosher.

Comment: @SethJ ... and apropos of the first issue you took with this post, don't worry - no prized out-of-print books were harmed in the production of these photos.

Comment: @SethJ the easiest way to legally get a $500k tax refund is to overpay taxes by $500k

Answer (score 1):

It says O K'man - Like Who.

You are supposed to find out who says this product is kosher and go to the link to publicize that Man Deamar