# What is the bracha for iPhone?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Before using an iPhone, what bracha should I say? On one side, it's Apple, so it could be "bore peri haetz". But on the other side, it is made of metal, so it could also be "bore peri matechet".

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: technically, the bracha on metal is borei minei ha'adamah

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/80768/759 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55508/759

Answer (score 6):

Before saying a bracha on an iPhone, you **first need to make sure it is kosher**. The laws of kosher phones are complicated but **many hold that iPhones are [not kosher](http://www.ravaviner.com/2016/01/short-sweet-test-message-q-313.html)**. For instance, the iPhone does not meet the criteria of kosher phones according to the [Vaad Harabonim](http://cellularisrael.com/content.php?cid=4) or the [Star-K](http://venishmartem.com/devices/mobiles/item/unlocked-kosher-phones) (under the guidance of Rabbi Moshe Heinemann).

The Shulchan Aruch ([Orah Hayyim 196:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.196.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) rules that non-kosher items **do not require before or after brachot**. However if you use an iPhone in emergency mode *in case of danger*, then SA ([OC 204:9](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayyim.204.9?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)) rules that you do need a bracha before and after.

I can see two solutions if you persist in wanting to use an iPhone

1. There is an Apple Kashruth Commission (see logo below) that certifies some models and you could [check with them](http://www.kosheratlanta.org/).

[image: Apple Kashruth Commission]

2. Some poskim (e.g., [R Aviner](http://www.ravaviner.com/2016/01/short-sweet-test-message-q-313.html)) hold that phones don't need to be kosher if you won't stumble with them. So CYLOR (check with your local orthodox repairman).

In these two cases, don't forget to say *she-ekhianu* the first time you use your new iPhone.

Comment: Related: [What is the Torah preferred brand of cell phone?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55508/5151)

Comment: I think Iphone got a hechsher from [this agency](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14951/4794)