# PTIJ: Does a Jewish web site need to have challah taken?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

If a Jewish web site plans on putting a lot of cookies on your computer, does it need to have challah taken from it, before placing the cookies? Is there a minimum number of cookies before challah is required, and if so, what would that be?

If the web site didn't have challah taken, do you need to do this? If so, what would be the best procedure to do it?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Is challah actually taken from cookies? I was under the impression it’s only taken from Hamotzi dough. Is this only a stringency since it’s פת הבא בכיסנין?

Comment: very related (to the point of this one not being so original)  https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/89349/4794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Star-K website

One should be mafrish Challah when kneading 2.6 lbs. of flour, which on average is equivalent to 8.667 cups of flour. However, a bracha is not recited for this amount. If one kneads a smaller amount of flour, one is not mafrish Challah.

There are two customs as to the amount that must be kneaded to require a bracha. Some individuals recite a bracha when kneading 3.675 lbs. or more of flour (on average, 12.25 cups). Many only recite a bracha when kneading 4.95 lbs. of flour (i.e. almost the entire contents of a 5 lb. bag of flour – on average, 16.5 cups of flour). Individuals should follow their family custom.

Now a website weighs nothing and virtual cookies also have no weight so Challa would not be taken for this.

Answer (score 3):

Since the internet is treif, the cookies formed from internet are also treif. One doesn’t take Challah from treif dough.

Comment: So, the fact that you answered this question implies that you're getting benefit from treif. Here ... have a cookie.

Comment: @DanF one may benefit from (most) treif foods. I promise not to eat neither the internet nor its cookies.