# PTIJ: Please accept our Hamantaschen policy?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Does anyone know why numerous websites are suddenly asking me to accept their Hamantaschen policy?
Does this have anything to do with GDPR?
[image: Hamantaschen policy]

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Which site is that?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/89349/ptij-how-do-i-know-if-miyodeya-cookies-are-kosher-what-should-i-do-on-pesach

Comment: I used a time machine to travel to the future, and took a screenshot of a Jewish satirical site that read this post from the past, and decided to do this shtick during Adar . You can thank causal loops for this!!!

Comment: Do the Hamentaschen have our [Mi Yodeya-guaranteed hechsher](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14951/) on them?